# Excel - How to delete the infinite blank rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

We have 5000 records of data.

For some reason, our Excel file has over a million rows where every column is blank.

How can we get rid of these 1 million + empty rows?

Comment: Could you try to provide a sample? If all blank cells in each same row, you can try to filter blank first and then delete directly.

Comment: if you open a brand new blank Excel workbook, do you see the same blank rows there? It has always been the case that Excel starts out with a set of blank rows and columns rather than requiring the user to expand the usable area only when they need to. Since they are empty, they usually have no impact on anything.
If you delete them, they will be replaced so that the number of rows and columns is always the same.

Comment: Yup, as others has said, a large number of blank rows  remain at the bottom for you to insert data where ever you like. If however you have lots of blank rows sandwiched (bottom and top) between actual rows of data, your data source may be responsible. Add a filter,  filter for blanks only.  Select all visible blank rows (but not past the legitimate blanks at the bottom, right-click and delete.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Home tab -> Find & Select -> Go to Special
2. Select Blanks. Click OK.

[image]

3. The blank cells will be highlighted. Go to Home tab -> Delete. Select Delete Sheet Rows. The blank rows will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong answer... this will select all rows containing one empty cell, not empty trailing rows created by inserting more data deleted after by user.

Easiest way to get rid of them is to select all data from current sheet and paste it into new one (there will be no trailing rows)